# BASH grep script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, loops, grep

I am trying to work on a bash script that checks for a username in the argument of the script and then outputs the relevant lines from the /etc/passwd and /etc/group files (not the /etc/shadow file). Currently, I am utilizing a if then else loop to check the contents of the /etc/* directory and output the relevant information. My intention was to output simple text line if a match user is not found in the two files, thus a null value. However, it is outputting information that is totally incorrect for what I am looking for.As a new user to BASH, and linux is general, I am sure there are some glaring issues right away. However, I am trying to learn.

Any help with the code of my script or a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
#! /bin/bash                                                              


USERLOOK='grep -h $USERID ~/etc/* | grep :x:'                       

grep $1 ~/etc/*                                                     
if [ -z $1 ]; then                                                        
    echo "User not found."                                            
else                                                                      
    echo "$USERLOOK"                                                  
fi                                                                        
exit 0
```

Comment: Question not clear? You wish to enter the username as an argument to script say `./script user_to_check`?

Comment: You should read up on [quoting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Practices#Quoting) and [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution).

Comment: @sjsam Yes, I want to have the script function where I input ./script user_to_check.   If the username is found, I want to output all lines where it was found, that was my reasoning for using grep. However, if the username was not found, I wanted to echo that.

Comment: @Cyrus Thanks for the link. I have tried spellcheck a couple of times with various iterations of this script. While some return no errors, the output was never really what I was looking for. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finds any lines in `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/group` that contain the inputted username:

```
#!/bin/bash

USERLOOK=$(grep -h "$1" /etc/passwd /etc/group)

if [ -z "$1" ] || [ -z "${USERLOOK}" ]; then
    echo "User not found."
else
    echo "$USERLOOK"
fi
```

Comment: the `:x:` won't work for `/etc/shadow`, and anyway you should anchor the search to the beginning of the line, e.g. `"^$1:"`

Comment: You may wish to replace the legacy backticks with `$()`

Comment: Thank you for the response. This definitely works better that what I initially have, however, I was trying to return all lines from both files that contain the username that was input in the script arguments.    Also, I do see some syntax errors that I made based on this script, so thank you for that as well.

Comment: Also, am I correct in thinking that the first line of the IF statement is just looking for a blank argument, or would that function the same if the username is not found in either of the two files?

Comment: Okay, I saw the `:x:` in your question and figured you were looking for only those lines, I've updated the script to include all lines and also check for empty input.

Comment: @jchavannes I believe that script is working exactly as I intended. Would you mind me asking a questions in regards to your script?  In the first line of the if statement, are you checking for a null value if a user does not enter a username in the arguments, as well as a null value should the USERLOOK variable not find a matching username in the passed and group files?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to have the script function where I input ./script
>   user_to_check. If the username is found, I want to output all lines
>   where it was found... However, if the username was not found, I wanted
>   to echo that.

It can be as simple as

```
#!/bin/bash
grep "^${1}:" /etc/passwd   /etc/group
[ $? -ne 0 ] && echo "User : ${1} not found"
```

As the user name appears in the beginning in both `/etc/passwd` & `/etc/group` we placed a `^` in grep to match stuff at beginning and by tradition a `:` appears just after the username.

Run the script as

```
./script 'username'
```

Comment: use `"^$1:"` else you could get a user `foobar` when calling `./script foo`

Comment: Thank you for the response. This does return the first username value. However, I am trying to return all lines the contain the username that was input, thus my initial reasoning for utilizing grep.

Comment: @mona_sax Once again, thanks for the help. I just typed out that script with a username that I know is present in the file, but it still returns a not found.      In another response, I clarified a little more with what I was trying to do with this script:   " I want to have the script function where I input ./script user_to_check. If the username is found, I want to output all lines where it was found, that was my reasoning for using grep. However, if the username was not found, I wanted to echo that."

Comment: @NewBashUser226 : See the update please. Pls gimme n update if this helped?

Comment: @mona_sax That script seems to be printing only a single line from the group file, as well as the path to the group file before the output. In my original code, I was able to output multiple lines from both the passed and group files, which was my intention. However, that script obviously has errors.

Comment: @NewBashUser226 : As I can confirm, this will print lines from both `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group`. If you dont want the filepath at the beginning, you could use the `-h` option with `grep` ie do `grep -h "^${1}:" /etc/passwd   /etc/group`.

Comment: @mona_sax Thanks for the help. Your script actually helped me research a couple more topics and I will look into your methodology versus mine as well. However, I believe the script that jchavannes posted answers my question and utilizes code that is closer to my new user skill level.

Answer (score 0):

Stop, you're thinking about this all wrong.

A UNIX shell is an environment from which to call UNIX tools with a language to sequence those calls, that is all. The general purpose UNIX tool to manipulate text is awk. So if you need to look for text in a file and have control logic to do anything with it, that should be an awk script, not a shell script. Shells role is to just call awk, something like this:

```
awk -v user="$1" '
$0 ~ user { line = $0 }
END { print (line != "" ? line : "User not found") }
' /etc/passwd /etc/group
```

but note that it's trivial with awk to focus the search on just one field, even a different field for each file, unlike how difficult that is in general with grep.